# Adding a Image Service layer to an ArcMap project with ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects

I would like to add an ArcGIS Image Service programmaticaly using ArcObjects. My Image Service specs are below.

Data Type: ArcGIS Image Service
Service Name: Aerial Imagery 2008
AIS Service URL: ImageService://gisimage/2008_DOQQ
Data Representation Type: RGB

Thanks in advance.

Jorge

Answer (score 0):

See the example here:
http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISServer/apis/ArcObjects/esriCarto/IImageServerLayer.htm

Use IImageServerLayer instead of IImageServerLayer2 though.